# How to Crop an Image before Image Classification with TFLite on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, machine-learning, crop, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to create an app that can classify an image using TFlite, based upon a learned model created on Teachable Machine.

I am struggling to find a way to give the user an option to crop the image before it is classified. Here is my code for the Java class:

```
package com.example.app;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.media.ThumbnailUtils;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.app.R;
import com.example.app.ml.Model;

import org.tensorflow.lite.DataType;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.tensorbuffer.TensorBuffer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView result, confidence;
    ImageView imageView;
    Button picture;
    int imageSize = 224;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        result = findViewById(R.id.result);
        confidence = findViewById(R.id.confidence);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        picture = findViewById(R.id.button);

        picture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Launch camera if we have permission
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1);
                    } else {
                        //Request camera permission if we don't have it.
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 100);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void classifyImage(Bitmap image){
        try {
            Model model = Model.newInstance(getApplicationContext());

            // Creates inputs for reference.
            TensorBuffer inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(new int[]{1, 224, 224, 3}, DataType.FLOAT32);
            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4 * imageSize * imageSize * 3);
            byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

            int [] intValues = new int[imageSize * imageSize];
            image.getPixels(intValues, 0, image.getWidth(), 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
            int pixel = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < imageSize; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < imageSize; j++){
                    int val = intValues[pixel++]; // RGB
                    byteBuffer.putFloat(((val >> 16 ) & 0xFF) * (1.f / 255.f));
                    byteBuffer.putFloat(((val >> 8 ) & 0xFF) * (1.f / 255.f));
                    byteBuffer.putFloat((val & 0xFF  ) * (1.f / 255.f));
                }
            }

            inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer);

            // Runs model inference and gets result.
            Model.Outputs outputs = model.process(inputFeature0);
            TensorBuffer outputFeature0 = outputs.getOutputFeature0AsTensorBuffer();


            float[] confidences = outputFeature0.getFloatArray();
            int maxPos = 0;
            float maxConfidence = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < confidences.length; i++){
                if(confidences[i] > maxConfidence){
                    maxConfidence = confidences[i];
                    maxPos = i;
                }
            }
            String[] classes = {"Negative", "+/-100", "250", "500", "1000", ">=2000"};

            result.setText(classes[maxPos]);

            String s = "";
            for(int i = 0; i < classes.length; i++){
                s += String.format("%s: %.1f%%\n", classes[i], confidences[i] * 100);
            }

            confidence.setText(s);


            // Releases model resources if no longer used.
            model.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Handle the exception
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            int dimension = Math.min(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
            image = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(image, dimension, dimension);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(image);

            image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, imageSize, imageSize, false);
            System.out.println(image);
            classifyImage(image);

        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

This is the video tutorial I followed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jhGm4KDafKU

I found a tutorial to be able to crop an image from your gallery and display it in the image view, however I wasn't able to link this with my image classification. This is the part of the code I edited to try and link these together:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == 101){
        String result = data.getStringExtra("CROP");
        Uri uri = data.getData();


        if (result!=null){
            uri = Uri.parse(result);
        }

        binding.imageView.setImageURI(uri);
      

       // I added this:

        try {

            Bitmap image = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);

            int dimension = Math.min(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());

            image = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(image, dimension, dimension);

            image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, imageSize, imageSize, false);
       
            classifyImage(image);
  
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        

    }
}
```

However, it always results in the activity crashing, these are the errors:

```
I/BitmapCropTask: Should crop: true
I/tflite: Initialized TensorFlow Lite runtime.
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.phoenixapp, PID: 21124
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=101, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.phoenixapp/com.example.phoenixapp.Tensor}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5301)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5340)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:54)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2210)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.phoenixapp.Tensor.classifyImage(Tensor.java:113)
        at com.example.phoenixapp.Tensor.onActivityResult(Tensor.java:184)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8382)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5294)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5340) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:54) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2210) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 21124 SIG: 9
```

Is there a simple solution to be able to perform image classification, whilst being able to crop the image beforehand?

Comment: What crash you are getting ? Please post your logcat ?

Comment: @ahjo4321hsotuhsa Hi, thanks for the comment, I added the errors I'm getting after attempting to crop a photo for it to be put through the image classifier. The activity just seems to crash and it returns to the previous activity page. Apologies, if I'm not using any terminology correctly, I'm just getting started with this stuff.

Comment: Check if  uri if null  or not before setting this       binding.imageView.setImageURI(uri);

Comment: @ahjo4321hsotuhsa it's not null. I believe that was part of the code from the cropping tutorial that set the cropped image to be displayed in the imageView?

Comment: @ahjo4321hsotuhsa 
```
Bitmap image = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);

System.out.println("check 1 " + image);

int dimension = Math.min(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());

image = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(image, dimension, dimension);

System.out.println("check 2 " + image);

image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, imageSize, imageSize, false);

System.out.println("check 3 " + image);

classifyImage(image);
```

Comment: @ahjo4321hsotuhsa I added these print statements to check the status of "image" at different points and I get this:


    I/System.out: check 1 android.graphics.Bitmap@76c1c11 
 
    I/System.out: check 2 android.graphics.Bitmap@76c1c11

    I/System.out: check 3 android.graphics.Bitmap@fbb5176